# display distinct records sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

My cursor is returning records twice even though I set the distinct to true:

**return myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] 
                {"rowid as _id", KEY_CONDITIONS}, builder.toString(), symptoms, null, null, null, null);**

**FYI,**

```
   public Cursor getData(String[] symptoms) {
    String where = KEY_SYMPTOMS + "= ?";
    String orStr = " OR "; 

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(where);
    for(int i = 1; i < symptoms.length; i++)
        builder.append(orStr).append(where);

    return myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] 
            {"rowid as _id", KEY_CONDITIONS}, builder.toString(), symptoms, null, null, null, null);

}
```

Or I tried to change to rawQuery

```
    return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_CONDITIONS + " FROM " 
    + DB_TABLE + " " + builder.toString() + symptoms.toString(), null);
```

My LogCat says:

```
  03-02 22:57:02.634: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-02 22:57:02.634: E/AndroidRuntime(333): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT conditions FROM tblSymptoms symptoms= ? OR symptoms= ?[Ljava.lang.String;@405550f8
```

Please help me identify what seems to be missing in here. Any help is truly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**
You want `DISTINCT` conditions but Android requires the `_id` column which is a problem because you cannot mix and match: <strike>`SELECT _id, DISTINCT condition...`</strike>.  However you can use the `GROUP BY` clause instead:

```
return myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {"rowid as _id", KEY_CONDITIONS}, 
        builder.toString(), symptoms, KEY_CONDITIONS, null, null);
```

---

**Explanations**
This query:

```
return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_CONDITIONS + " FROM " 
    + DB_TABLE + " " + builder.toString() + symptoms.toString(), null);
```

Failed because you are passing `String[] symptoms` in the wrong parameter, try:

```
return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_CONDITIONS + " FROM " 
    + DB_TABLE + " " + builder.toString(), symptoms);
```

---

This query:

```
return myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] {"rowid as _id", KEY_CONDITIONS}, builder.toString(), symptoms, null, null, null, null);
```

Failed because `DISTINCT` is looking at *both* the id and condition columns. It is the equivalent of: `SELECT DISTINCT(_id, conditions) ...` You, obviously, only want distinct conditions...

Comment: Yes obviously I want distinct conditions. Please see my update post about my table records

Comment: I tried to execute this query in SQLite Browser: Select DISTINCT conditions FROM tblsymptoms where symptoms = 'Chest Pain' OR symptoms = 'Dizziness' It displayed distinct conditions. I wonder why it's not displaying distinct in Android?

Comment: Which query are you using? Did you try the `rawQuery()` above? The `query()` fails because it's SQL equivalent is: `Select DISTINCT (rowid, conditions) FROM tblsymptoms where ...`. Notice the difference?

Comment: I think I forgot to include WHERE clause

Comment: Ha! :) That would give you a different set of results.  Anyway try my new `query()` that uses `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Okay just a minute I'll try groupby

Comment: Thanks Sam! You've been a big help to me. Your code works well.

Answer (score 0):

you have two general option two do this Task
**use row query **and
**use DISTINCT keyword**

for using **row query** you can directly use function of mr.Sam
and for using DISTINCT keyword you can use

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, 
                 String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy,
                 String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

because query stucher is `retuns`this:

```
query(false, table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy,
            having, orderBy, null /* limit */);
```

in this code first arg is for `DISTINCT` so provide it as `true`.
so your `query` will like this

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, YOUR_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN1 ,COLUMN2, COLUMN_NAME_3 }, null, null, COLUMN2, null, null, null);
```

Basically**DISTINCT keyword** returns a column name only once if it apperase more then one time.